# What are some examples of 2-polytope/3-polytope that are not simple?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polytopes, discrete-geometry

I've learned lots of stuffs in class about how to identify a simple polytope. But I've never seen a counter-example.

We use the following definition of simple polytope:

[image]

Comment: "Simplicial" means it only has simplex (triangle) facets. A counter-example is a cube. I assume this isn't what you meant.

Comment: @mr_e_man sorry my question shouldn't include that part about simplicial. I'll edit it. Thanks.

Comment: You won't find a 2-polytope (polygon) counter-example. They are all simple and simplicial, because every vertex figure and every facet (edge) is a 1-simplex (line segment).

Comment: You could really not find an example? Did you not think to ask this in class while you were learning all that stuff that you were learning about simple polytopes?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez what's the difference between asking there and asking here? It's not like we spent the whole lecture musing about what is and what is not a simple polytope.

Comment: I am very certain that all that you learned about how to identify simple polytopes would have been infinitely much more productive if you had had examples of non-simple polytopes. If you do not have any example of a non-simple polytope, how do you possibly understand how a test to see whether a polytope is simple or not works?

Comment: Given the definition of simplicity you mentioned in the question, to find an example of a non-simple polytope you need only find a 3-polytope which has a vertex which is contained in 4 facets. I am amazed that you cannot find an example of that. I bet that if you mention 3 polytopes, at least one of them is non-simple.

Comment: When you phrase the definition like that, it helps. But I don't see how me taking the sarcasm and rhetorical questions from you would. My brain is tired, and I agree this is not the brightest question ever been asked, but this reaction is just disappointing.

Comment: I am not being sarcastic. I am simply suggesting better ways to deal with your problem, thay of not having an example of a non-simple polytope while at the same time being taught how to recognize simple polytopes. Notice that I did not "phrase" anything: the definion of simple that quoted says exactly that.

Comment: As an instructor, there are very few things more disappointing than having a student **not** ask such an obvious question as the one you had at the time it popped in your mind. Much effort is lost uselessly after that, on both sides.

Comment: In the end, it is not the definition of simplicity or examples of non-simple polytopes that you need to learn: what you need to learn is how to learn, how to take the most advantage of your classes and other sources of instruction, how to pick a definition and find examples and non-examples. Don't let anyone talk to you about an object which you simply don't understand, much as you would probably object if your teacher started to do lectures in Croatian.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the dual of a non-simplicial polytope. For example, a cube's dual is an octahedron, which has 4 edges per vertex, not 3.

Comment: Not every simplicial polytope works, though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant non-simplicial. I'll edit.

Comment: (I would guess that this only transforms the problem of the OP into "I've never seen an example of a non-simplicial polytope"…)